# If a empty model exists, can I use rails g model blah to add properties quickly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If a empty model exists, can I use rails g model blah to add properties quickly?

Comment: by properties, do you mean columns?

Answer (score 3):

You can also add properties quickly during a migration without even having to touch the migration file. For example, to add 3 new fields to the User model:

```
rails g migration AddFieldsToUser field1:string field2:integer field3:datetime
```

And then just run the migration.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a migration file, this will create a new migration and ask us whether to overwrite fixtures, tests, and model(if there is any change). If the migration already exists, it will say 'another migration is already named ...'.